# Codeigniter 3 Cli not working

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am currently working with codeigniter3 and I have a problem with calling a function. To execute function in Cli, I used the command in terminal: "php index.php tools(controller) message(function in controller)". However, it does not access function and only prints index.php contents.

I have set uri_protocol in config file as 'AUTO'. How do I access function in Cli? Am I using wrong command?

Comment: Codeigniter 3 uri_protocol does not have AUTO.

Comment: you can refere this Link for your reference : http://www.asim.pk/2009/05/14/creating-and-installing-crontabs-using-codeigniter/

Comment: whats error your are getting ?

Comment: it only prints out index.php without calling function.

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but do you have `<?php` at the top of your index.php file?